# How to get Text box to horizontally scroll over inserted widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

If I create a text box and fill it with text longer than the width of the text box the scroll bar works fine. 
Like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

vbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal")
vbar.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="NWSE")
text_box = tk.Text(root, width=50, height=30, xscrollcommand=vbar.set, wrap=tk.NONE)
text_box.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=(5, 5))
text_box.grid_propagate(0)
vbar.config(command=text_box.xview)

for n in range(0, 60):
    text_box.insert(tk.END,"*")

root.mainloop()
```

But I want to insert text boxes in this main text box and scroll across them horizontally. It inserts two of the text boxes but the scroll bar is not activated so I can't view the 3rd text box. I don't want the textbox to expand to accommodate the nested text boxes hence `text_box.grid_propagate(0)`

Is there any way of doing this?

Here is the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

vbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal")
vbar.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="NWSE")
text_box = tk.Text(root, width=50, height=30, xscrollcommand=vbar.set, wrap=tk.NONE)
text_box.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=(5, 5))
text_box.grid_propagate(0)
vbar.config(command=text_box.xview)

tweet_windows = ["Window 1", "Window 2", "Window 3"]

for n in range(0, len(tweet_windows)):
    tweet_windows[n] = tk.Text(text_box, width=23)
    tweet_windows[n].grid(column=n, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured this out. You need to generate the number of text widgets you need to nest but not `grid` them. Then place them inside the main text widget using the `.create_window` method of the main text widget. The nested widgets can be referenced and updated in the usual way.

Here's the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

vbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal")
vbar.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="NWSE")
text_box = tk.Text(root, width=50, height=30, xscrollcommand=vbar.set, wrap=tk.NONE)

text_box.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=(5, 5))
text_box.grid_propagate(0)
vbar.config(command=text_box.xview)

text1 = tk.Text(width=23)
text1.insert(tk.END, "test")
text2 = tk.Text(width=23)
text2.insert(tk.END, "test2")
text3 = tk.Text(width=23)
text3.insert(tk.END, "test3")

text_box.window_create(tk.END, window=text1)
text_box.window_create(tk.END, window=text2)
text_box.window_create(tk.END, window=text3)

text3.insert(tk.END, "\nMore text")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I've added it to the code. Missed it during copy and paste. What do you mean by "shift + scrolling"?

Comment: Nevermind. The initial code piece lets the user scroll horizontally using shift + scrolling in windows. This one does too, when the largest textbox has focus.

Comment: Oh with the mouse wheel right. I didn't know you could scroll horizontally with the mouse wheel anyway Lol. Interesting. I'll look into some more, but it's not that high up on my priority list. Thanks for the info though.